# Is it "bad practice" to use tab characters in string literals?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, string-literals

As a follow-up on [Is it mandatory to escape tabulator characters in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900842/is-it-mandatory-to-escape-tabulator-characters-in-c-and-c) (do note I'm not the author of said question).

I've learned such code is considered "bad practice". The comments seem to be suggesting the same thing. However, for some reason the standard allows this trickery so somebody must either found no harm in it or has a use-case for it.

Is not escaping tabulator characters widely accepted as "bad practice"?

Comment: Probably no one has done a survey, it has long been poor practice, if for no other reason than that it is too easy to break code by accidentally converting tabs to spaces.  I flag those in my code-counter http://invisible-island.net/c_count/c_count.html

Comment: C in general doesn't try to protect programmers from doing dumb things. It's easier to allow this than to forbid it and the assumption is that the programmer knows what they're doing. "Doctor, it hurts when I do this. - Don't do that."

Comment: I'd consider it bad practice because it's easy to mistake for a couple of spaces.

Comment: If the `\t` is a character then why would it be bad or invalid?

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's why I am always afraid of programmers who only know python or C#.

Comment: @iharob: The question is a bit confusing because the original question had an inverse title, but I think he's saying that _not_ escaping tabular characters is bad practice.

Comment: @iharob That philosophy is why I'm afraid of writing C and C++. Optimizing compilers prey on your tiniest mistakes and can wreck your whole program when they find one.

Comment: @iharob I'm not afraid of compilation failing, I'm afraid of the compiler finding some subtle case of UB. For example ensuring a program is free of integer overflows is a lot of effort. Or some out of bounds array access in a case that didn't test (so even valgrind doesn't catch it) leading to a remote code execution vulnerability. Writing C and C++ requires being a programmer than I am.

Comment: I realized that now and deleted the comment.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Actually both are pretty easy if you write idiomatic C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using tabs in litterals instead of escaping them (`'\t'`,"\t") is a bad practice because :

- the reader is not immediately aware that there is a tab. Consequence: wrong assumptions about code, wrong changes (for example when allignemnt of code output needs to be adapted)
- the tab expansion might be different depending on your editor.  Consequence:  hindering of teamwork and maintenance, as different people may see different layouts.
- MOST OF ALL:  some editors convert tabs to spaces when saving your source file (using the configured tab expansion settings) getting rid of such embedded tabs.  Consequence: unnoticed/undesired change (f.ex:  when a teammember uses such an editor and make a minor edit, not even in this string).

Comment: @zenith The second point makes it a bad practice, because it hinders teamwork and maintenance.  Example:  Programmer A embeds tab in the string using tab stops of 8.  Programmer B has to maintain the code, opens it with tab stops of 4, makes some changes that shift the place of the tab in the line.  Output seems sunddenly to be misaligned, so he'll add another tab, etc...

Comment: @Christophe: That's quite an incompetent developer if he's arbitrarily adding tabspaces to a string literal for a bad reason like that! Of course, such incompetent developers do exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Taht's it:  the world isn't perfect !...  And I wouldn't blame such a guy:  the tab-expansion feature that many professional editors offer, demonstrate that most people assume that tabs are used in code for indenting, and not as litterals. Nobody should go against such popular thoughts ;-)

Comment: @Christophe: Even _that_ assumption is broken, since auto-converting tab indentation to evil space indentation is the devil's work.

Answer (score 3):

I've never really thought about it, but I can't imagine finding literal tabspace characters a good idea because you cannot immediately distinguish them from standard whitespace. If you need a tabspace in your string literal for some specific reason, it's more clear and explicit to write `\t` so that everybody knows precisely what you intended to do.

By the way, the notion that there must be a good use case just because the standard allows it … is somewhat broken. For example, the standard allows us to declare raw pointers, and to write `new`.

Comment: Y'know what? [This answer was already given on the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28901052/560648). I'm not really sure I understand why you had to re-ask it.

Comment: Simple. I'm not an expert and the comments seem to say the compiler will take care of it anyway. When in doubt, ask. That's how Q&A works, right?

Comment: @Mast: The compiler will "take care of" what?

Comment: Lightness, the prior research is my experience with both languages. I can understand why it shouldn't be done, but I've seen things in the past which I couldn't agree to be a good practice. So, instead of accepting comments on a related question as an answer, I posted my own question. To prevent mistakenly accepting wrong statements.